# Azure # many sites - one login ( Single Sign On )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

Plan :

Many asp net 4.5 sites hosted on azure  (will be mapped to different domains) -->

How to share login between the sites?

Option 1 :

Use 1 database for all sites - how each site login and which site is the "master site" which hold

the database?

Option 2 :

Use database for each site with extra 1 global database for users(+forums posts)

Option 3 :  ( combine 1+2 ?! )

2 database , 1 for users users(+forums posts) + 1 for data

Either option , I don't know  how to do it ...

I'm using [CodeFirst Membership Provider](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/)

- If I login to SiteA is like login for SiteB  and etc ( you got the point )
- Is it "same domain" if all sites sits on Azure?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Azure Access Control Service (ACS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/hh147631.aspx) which is a part of Windows Azure Active Directory.

Create one ACS namespace and add all your applications urls as relying parties in this namespace through the portal. After that you need to Add a STS Reference from Visual Studio  (that comes up when you install Windows Identity Foundation) for each of your application by giving the url of your ACS service namespace.

You will have to add your custom Identity Provider against which you need to do authentication. For example, in your scenario you can have a single database and create a custom STS that authenticates using forms authentication, and you will have to use the url of this service as your Identity Provider in ACS namespace. You have option to Add default identity providers such as Windows Live, Google, Yahoo and Facebook as well in case you want.

For some detailed steps refer this [link](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control)

There are few sample codes available at [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385) as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Use database for each site with extra 1 global database for users

This option sounds good for me.

You can use CAS (Central Authentication Service) and this way you'll have a central point to authenticate the users. CAS will be configured to authenticate in the Global Database.

**It's necessary to configure each ASP Application to authenticate using CAS.

The basic authenticate flow is:

1. User tries access a specific ASP site.
2. The ASP site identifies that the users isn't authenticated and redirect the user to CAS (that runs in other web site).
3. User types your login and password.
4. CAS checks in the Global Database if the login and password are correct.
5. If yes, CAS redirects the user to the specific ASP site (step 1).

You will need to install Java and Tomcat (or other java application server) to run CAS. Because of that, I don't know if CAS is a good option for you.

http://www.jasig.org/cas

I'm using CAS authenticating against an Active Directory instance.

Sorry my english.

Comment: I think that the only option to use Azure with CAS is to use a Virtual Machine plan (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines).

Comment: I prefer not using Visual Machine , I wanna it simple , using Publish my sites

Comment: You're right Zakos. Keep it simple it's better. Well, anyway, in the future if you want to try CAS, you can use a small Virtual Machine running CAS (https) and a small database to authenticate the users. The ASP sites will continue running in Azure with Publishing.